# Annotating a TypeScript function that allows an array or a spread of params as arguments?

Tags: typescript, annotations

I want to write a function called `printNums()` that allows for both:

```
printNums(1, 2, 3)
printNums([1, 2, 3])
```

In plain JS, the function would look something like:

```
function printNums(nums) {
  if (!Array.isArray(nums)) {
    nums = [...arguments]
  }

  nums.forEach(num => {
    console.log(`Num: ${num}`)
  })
}
```

In TypeScript, how would I write/annotate the `nums` param?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is an overload:

```
function printNums(...nums: number[]): void;
function printNums(nums: number[]): void;
function printNums(num1: number | number[], ...nums: number[]) {
  // safer than using [...arguments].
  const normalizedNums = Array.isArray(num1) ? num1 : [num1, ...nums];

  normalizedNums.forEach(num => {
      console.log(`Num: ${num}`)
  })
}
```

Comment: What does `...nums` do in the method parameter?

Comment: @MuratKaragöz It's known as Rest parameters in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as well as helping with the type safety!

Answer (score 1):

You can use overloads:

```
function printNums(...nums: number[]): void
function printNums(nums: number[]): void
function printNums(nums: number[] | number) {
    if (!Array.isArray(nums)) {
        nums = [...arguments] // not type safe but it will work
    }

    nums.forEach(num => {
        console.log(`Num: ${num}`)
    })
}
```

Comment: You answered first, but I'm going to accept the answer by Madara Uchiha because they gave a better type-safe alternative. Upvoted, thanks!

Comment: @saadq sure no problem. I did think about including a the rest of the parameters but decided against it as the `...` will cause the data to first be copied to the extra param and then you copy it again to the final array (at least when targeting es5).. not ideal for a large abount of data but depends what you favor, type safety or perf